# CSS: Is there a Unit that the Equivalent to vh + vw?

Tags: javascript, html, css, resize, viewport-units

I am wondering if there is a unit for font size that `measures 1% of the width and height of a page`? I think it will make it easier for me, and help me do what I am trying to do, without having to use `JavaScript` (Although, any answer is acceptable, as long as it works). If there isn't a unit like that, how can I manipulate the font to do that? The only other thing I can think of is `%` but, I don't know if they work.

My problem comes, when I try to resize the page both ways. It works for it's intended purpose, but when you resize the page really small, it wont look good. And I'm a perfectionist and it bothers me when it doesn't work. Here is my code (It is a snipet of my code to be exact. If you want the full code, I will edit it onto here):

**Update(0.1):**
I am trying to make a better answer using javascript. I am not done with the code yet. Here it is:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var h11a = document.getElementById("h1_1_a");
  var w = window.innerWidth;
  var h = window.innerHeight;
  window.addEventListener("resize", function() {
    var w2 = window.innerWidth;
    var h2 = window.innerHeight;
    if (w > w2) {
      h11a.style.fontSize = "calc(6*(0vh + 1.5vw))";
    } else if (h > h2) {
      h11a.style.fontSize = "calc(6*(3vh + 0vw))";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  margin: 0%;
}
.div_1 {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  Height: 20%;
  background-color: #000000;
  border-top: .4vh solid #ff7400;
  border-left: .4vh solid #ff7400;
  border-right: .4vh solid #ff7400;
  border-bottom: .2vh solid #ff7400;
}
#div_1_a {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
#h1_1_a {
  line-height: 100%;
  height: 60%;
  color: #ff7400;
  font-size:calc(6*(1vh + 1vw));
  white-space: nowrap
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="halloweenEvent1.css" type="text/css" />
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="description" content="A Halloween Event Website" />
  <meta name="keywords" content="Brad,Website,Personal,Information,Halloween" />
  <meta name="author" content="Bradley William Elko" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Halloween Event (Home)</title>
</head>

<body onload="myFunction()">
  <div class="div_1">
    <div id="div_1_a">
      <h1 id="h1_1_a">Halloween Website</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Demo of `calc( n * ( 1vh + 1vw ) )` [proposed by Dai](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40198207/402022).

```css
* 
  { 
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body
{
  margin:0%;
}
.div_1
{
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
  Height:20%;
  background-color:#000000;
  border-top:.4vh solid #ff7400;
  border-left:.4vh solid #ff7400;
  border-right:.4vh solid #ff7400;
  border-bottom:.2vh solid #ff7400;
}
#div_1_a
{
  height:100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
#h1_1_a
{
  line-height:100%;
  height:60%;
  color:#ff7400;
  font-size: calc( 6 * ( 1vh + 1vw ) );
  white-space: nowrap
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="halloweenEvent1.css" type="text/css"/>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <meta name="description" content="A Halloween Event Website"/>
    <meta name="keywords" content="Brad,Website,Personal,Information,Halloween"/>
    <meta name="author" content="Bradley William Elko"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Halloween Event (Home)</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="div_1">
      <div id="div_1_a">
        <h1 id="h1_1_a">Halloween Website</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

> I want the font size to be in accordance to the div it's held in (in this case )

What I undertand by that is that you want the text to keep the same proportions than the container. I'll dodge the problem by using SVG:

```css
* 
  { 
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body
{
  margin:0%;
}
.div_1
{
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
  Height:20%;
  background-color:#000000;
  border-top:.4vh solid #ff7400;
  border-left:.4vh solid #ff7400;
  border-right:.4vh solid #ff7400;
  border-bottom:.2vh solid #ff7400;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="halloweenEvent1.css" type="text/css"/>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <meta name="description" content="A Halloween Event Website"/>
    <meta name="keywords" content="Brad,Website,Personal,Information,Halloween"/>
    <meta name="author" content="Bradley William Elko"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Halloween Event (Home)</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="div_1">
        <svg class="svg" viewbox="0 0 100 20">
            <text fill="#ff7400" x="50" y="10" font-size="50%" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="central">Halloween Website</text>
        </svg>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The drawback is that you lose the semantics of `h1`.

Comment: Do you know of a way to make it, so that, when you resize horizontally, only the `vw` is affected, and when you resize vertically, only  the vh is affected?

Comment: @BradleyWilliamElko "when you resize horizontally, only the vw is affected, and when you resize vertically, only the vh is affected" that's how that works. I don't understand what do you want. I suggest to expand the question explaining what do you want.

Comment: I meant to say, instead of it taking the view height of the page it takes the view height of the div because, it is not the size of the page, but a portion of the page (20% the height of the page to be exact).

Comment: I want the font size to be in accordance to the div it's held in (in this case `<div class="div_1">`). And, sorry for taking a while to respond, it took me a while to think of what I wanted. PS: Change `1vh` to `.2vh`. I figured that part out but, now I need to figure the other part out.

Comment: I'm working on the java script for another answer (It will build of this answer), but this is the correct way. If I post an answer will you check it out? Also, thanks for helping!

Answer (score 2):

Use `calc( n * ( 1vh + 1vw ) )` where `n` is your chosen coefficient.

Comment: Is this for javascript?

Comment: @BradleyWilliamElko this is CSS, see [calc at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc). See also the [browser compatibility for calc](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc).

Comment: I've never used this so I am having a hard time figuring out where, specifically, to put it. What I mean is, In which one do I put it in, and do I put `width:calc(n*1vh +1vw))` or...?

Comment: @Theraot I checked out your links but, I'm still unsure, as to, how I implement this int CSS. Can you help me?

Comment: @BradleyWilliamElko this is CSS, you write it where you write CSS. Perhaps this is a case of the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Dai's answer is a replace for the unit of hv + vw which is the question in the title and a way to interprete your first paragraph. Then you go on saying that when you rezie your page "it wont look good"... ok, but how do you want to look? Edit: from the comments on the other answer you seem to want both aligment and resizing.

Comment: @Theraot  Yes I do. This answer the question, and I figured out how to use it but, I want it to still be center align in the div.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no such a unit but maybe `vmin` would be a solution for your problem.

**EDIT:**

If you want to center both vertically and horizontaly, you can use something like this:

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.wrapper__text {
  font-size: 30vmin;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="wrapper__text">My text</div>
</div>
```

Thanks to:

http://howtocenterincss.com/

Comment: But, I think this unit doesn't work on IE or Edge. I know vmax works.

Comment: IE and Edge support `vmin`. They don't support `vmax`.

Comment: This fixes the problem, but it doesn't keep the element in the div centered when horizontal resizing (shrinking). How Do I fix that?